# Is there any way to compare Toda date with another date in Django View?

Tags: python, django

I want to compare date between todays and another date. Is it possible to compare in django views.py.

I have tried like this:

```
current_date = date.today

another date = request.POST.get("date1")
# I am getting the another date from html input type date//

if current_date>another_date:
return something
else:
return something
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, yes. I just checked it out to be sure:

```
$ python
Python 3.9.7 (default, Oct  7 2021, 20:39:15) 
[GCC 10.2.1 20210110] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from datetime import date
>>> date.today() > date(2030, 1, 1)
False
>>> date.today() < date(2030, 1, 1)
True
```

Let's try this in a view:

```py
from datetime import date
def my_view(request):
    if date.today() > date(2022, 1, 1):
        ...
    ...
```

Comment: I tried this but its saying 

'<' not supported between instances of 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'str'

Comment: is there any other way ??

Comment: You should post your code and the error you get if you want an clearer answer. If my code does not yield the same error as yours, you have done something wrong. We need to see what you did to tell you.

Comment: current_date=date,.today()                
if current_date < show_date:
                    performer_obj.last_performed_date = show_date
                else:
                    performer_obj.upcoming_date = show_date

Comment: I added the code in the post but still i commented the code i wrote @Nicolas Appriou

Comment: First, `another date` should be `another_date` (without space). And it comes as a string from POST.get. So you should convert the string to date before comparing.